# op type not registered 'NonMaxSuppressionV3' tensorflow

Tags: android, tensorflow, object-detection

i trained my network with the `Mobilenet V1 SSD` model for `object detection` using the the `object detection demo` for android and it worked fine. Now I retrained the same network with the new `Mobilenet V2 SSDLite` model since it's 35% than the older model according to their [readme](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) in GitHub and when testing the new network with `Jupyter Notbook` it worked normally and gave the expected results but when I tried to implement it in my android project I got the following error :

```
org.tensorflow.TensorFlowException: Op type not registered
'NonMaxSuppressionV3' in binary running on localhost. Make sure the Op 
and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note 
that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib,
accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be donebefore importing the
graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
```

to my understanding by reading other posts with similar issue I need to build the library manually and add the missing op. If that the case how can I do that ? any information is much appreciated.